# Python - Run _thread with low CPU usage

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have recently finally was able to run multiprocessing with _thread and I really thought it was the perfect script as I wanted but of course, it was not.

**The issue:** The issue is that it takes a lot of CPU usage when I run threads of 10. Which means I can't run concurrently a lot of tasks. (Race condition?)

**What I want**

Basically what I'm looking for the script to run the thread without using a lot of CPU usage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7jIk.png - to run all the threads concurrently (at the same time as the picture) without taking a lot of CPU usage - If I do 10000 maybe it should kill my CPU but running etc 10 threads shouldn't take that much!

**Code**

```
def text():
    text = """

   Hello stack!

      """

    print(text)
    sys.exit()


def Checker(thread):
    global prod
    prod = int(thread) + 1
    _thread.start_new_thread(text, ())
    print('Profile-{} starting thread...'.format(prod))
    text()


def main():

    while True:
        try:
            accounts_num = int(input(Fore.WHITE + 'How many text do you wanna run? [NUMBERS] \n' + Fore.RESET))
        except ValueError:
            print(Fore.RED + "Stop being stupid" + Fore.RESET)
            continue
        else:
            jobs = []

            for i in range(0, accounts_num):
                p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Checker, args=(str(i),))
                jobs.append(p)
                time.sleep(.5)
                p.start()

            for p in jobs:
                p.join()

            sys.exit()
```

EDIT:

The issue is sitting at `_thread.start_new_thread(text, ())` where when this starts, It starts to eat up the CPU.

Comment: Almost all of your code (except for the irrelevant `time.sleep(.5)`) is cpu bound. Once you start more processes then your cpu cores you should expect 100% cpu eaten.

Comment: However if I run multiprocessing etc 100, It doesn't eat the CPU that much at all until the _thread runs. So might be a issue on _thread?

Comment: Python also doesn't allow true native threads (yes, thread is implemented as a native thread, but the GIL effectively forces execution in one thread). It just allows parallelism within the single process Python runs in. `multiprocess` allows you to use multiple cores. If your task is CPU-bound, you're not going to get speed-ups with multi-threading.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Oh so in that case, What could I do if I change up the whole thing in that case? Like what would be the best suggestions to do?

Comment: @Andres123 Cython is a great tool, C/C++-extensions also exist, and so is `multiprocessing`. I personally like Cython with the `nogil` keyword a lot, if you're willing to compile code. If not, just use `multiprocessing`. Just a reminder that on Windows, there is no effective copy-on-write for `os.fork`, so it must completely copy the existing process, so your code may be slower using `multiprocessing` on Windows than the single process vversion.

Comment: Oh you are right! But as you can see I do have multiprocessing and it works fine. However in my def Checker is where the issue is coming, if I remove the _thread then it will just run 1 and wait until its finished and then run another processing. but what I want is that it should run all of them together. Thats why im using the _thread. But maybe there is another way than just _thread?